# Are HTTP status codes considered "magic numbers"?

Tags: http-status-codes

Wikipedia's article on [Magic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) suggests that any constant should be assigned to a variable with a meaningful name.

Does the same practice apply to HTTP status codes, which are a well-defined standard? That is, when writing tests, should one do `assert response.status_code == HTTP_STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS` or is `assert response.status_code == 200` appropriate in this context?

Comment: Setting those numbers to constants that are named appropriately definitely helps in code maintenance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a constant you defined is a good idea. Using one defined by the language is a better idea. I'm not sure what language you are using but most languages have one. [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) [python](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)

Comment: Python uses the `httplib` library to define HTTP Status Codes as constants. See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, magic numbers are magic numbers even if they are well known and well documented.